# Problems in sendowl webhooks

Tags: webhooks

I am working on sendowl web-hook integration http://www.sendowl.com/support/knowledge_base_articles/23-using-web-hooks
I follow this article and set up the web hook. But when I test the web hook then send owl send empty data means empty array (data is in either post/get). Can anybody tell me why is this happening or any body has knowledge regarding to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

George here from SendOwl.  Order data is sent with each Web Hook request so if you're seeing it as empty I'd expect you're checking the wrong thing.  Maybe if you paste your code here the StackOverflow community can help check what you're doing.

Just so you know you can also contact support direct on support@sendowl.com

George

Comment: Ok thanks @George I contact to your support and solved my problem.